# How to replace a word with a link

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to replace a word and insert a link instead.
An example of how I want to do:

```
const text = "Edit src/App.js and save to reload."

return (
  <div className="App">
    <header className="App-header">
      <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
      <p>
        {text.replace("Edit", <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_new"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        ></a>)}
      </p>
    </header>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: Please read this over and come back with some details: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JS function [`string.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) expects two string parameters, but instead of the second string you supply a JSX **`<a>`** element.

Note that JSX is definitely not text, it may just look like it if you are not used to it. All JSX tags are translated into calls to `React.createElement()`, the result of which is a React object and not a string.

To solve it, you need to convert the string into parts, modify what needs modifying (while making sure that the React `key` requirement for items in a collection is fulfilled), then render the result, as in the following demo:

```js
class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const logo = null;
    const text = "Edit src/App.js and save to reload."

    // Create array:
    const parts = text.split(" ");

    // Modify array to contain JSX elements: one link, the rest Fragments, because every item
    // in a collection needs a key to prevent React warnings.
    // Also manually inserted back the spaces that went missing due to the split operation.
    for (let i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
      if (parts[i] === "Edit")
        parts[i] = <a key={i} className="App-link" href="https://reactjs.org" target="_new" rel="noopener noreferrer">Edit</a>;
      else
        parts[i] = <React.Fragment key={i}>{" " + parts[i]}</React.Fragment>;
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
            {parts}
          </p>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Home />, document.getElementById('react'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```